# What is equivalent of getf in Urn Lisp?

Tags: lisp

I just started learning Lisp using Urn Lisp. Trying this code `(getf (list :a 1 :b 2 :c 3) :a)` gives this error:

```
[ERROR] Cannot find variable 'getf'
Did you mean any of these?
  •let
  •if
  •set!
  •let*
  •self
  => <stdin>:[1:2 .. 1:5]
 1 │ (getf (list :a 1 :b 2 :c 3) :a)
   │  ^^^^ 
>
```

I tried all the above options but got errors. What is the Urn equivalent of `getf`?

Comment: have you tried `(list :a 1 :b 2 :c 3)`? what does that return?

Comment: second question, what output do you expect from `(getf (list :a 1 :b 2 :c 3) :a)`?

Comment: Try `(.> { :a 1 :b 2 :c 3 } :a)`.

Comment: i) for Question 1, Urn returns ("a" 1 "b" 2 "c" 3)

Comment: ii) for Question 2, i understand getf will return value of 1.

Comment: Trying (.> { :a 1 :b 2 :c 3 } :a) works - it returns value of 1 & :c returns 3. Thank you! May I ask where to reference ' .> ' ? Thank you.

Comment: There is no "Lisp language". It is a language family, whose members can be quite different from each other. You are learning Urn Lisp; so use its documentation, tutorials and examples, and not some other references that teach that there is a`getf`. Don't expect everything/anything to be the same or have an exact counterpart in another Lisp-like language.

Comment: "I'm learning Javascript via the K&R2 C book. Where is `#include <stdio.h>`? C-like languages are all the same, right?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `(.> { :a 1 :b 2 :c 3 } :a)`.

See also:

- https://urn-lang.com/tutorial/05-lua-to-lisp.html
- https://urn-lang.com/reference/01-reader.html#structs

Comment: Thank you for the references! I should focus on the Urn tutorials first than on other CL literature. Thank you!

Comment: if an answer has answered your question you can mark it as "accepted" (by clicking on the big empty V sign next to it) to show this. You will also get 2 reputation points from that. see ["what should I do when someone answers my question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). @gwbasic